# XCode: File not found error

Tags: c++, xcode, file, text, g++

I'm using writing a program in XCode and I can't I can't seem to get XCode to find a txt file that I need to read from (in order to test my program). The program compiles and runs appropriately with g++.

Thanks, Jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Xcode to see the file without using a path in your code, the file would need to be placed in a directory such as:

```
/Users/Jacob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SomeProjectName/Build/Products/Deb
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question, I couldn't find how to get it to read the file in the same directory as my .cpp file, however, I typed cout << argv[0] and that gave me the executable file directory, I put the file in there and it ran.